# Git on a Windows Lan

Tags: windows, git

My colleagues and I are thinking of giving git a try and see if we can easily move to it. We work on a Windows-only environment. On our own machines we already have git set up with mingw32 and SmartGit as gui client.

Is there an easy approach based more on the concept of sharing folders than on the concept of "hosting server"? For example, we wanted to host a git repository on a folder shared on the lan, clone it on our machines and see how to push our changes back to that folder, merge them and so on.

Our first problem was cloning from the lan. Of course git doesn't recognize paths like `\\mymachine\shared\repo`

How to start with our approach? Is to doable? Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

As suggested, a command line approach worked. We also had to invert the slashes, so that `git clone //machine/directory/repository` did the trick. Now, my colleague had a local copy working, made some changes... How to push them back to the shared folder?

Push and Fetch work on local paths too, we're up and running with our tests. Thank you all!

Comment: in response to your edit, `git push` on the command line with the remote repository specified should get you the push functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Pistacchio, Please share with me the actual setup you have, coz am trying the same thing but its failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice sidesteps your efforts a bit, but I've been using Mercurial in exactly the same approach you've described here, and if it's not too much of a plan change, I'd encourage you to give using [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) a try.  Mercurial works with file path based repositories exactly the same way it works with "served" repositories (e.g. it will recognize `\\server\shared_repo\repo_path` as a valid repository path to clone from.)

As an additional point, from what I can tell, Mercurial's Windows support is pretty far along, whereas git still has some fringe compatibility issues (although it appears that you've addressed many of the biggest challenges to using git on Windows already)

Comment: I wanted to quickly add the comment that this answer is quite old (and bad because I didn't answer the *question*). I'm upvoting the top voted answer to acknowledge the better answer.

Answer (score 19):

For a pure command-line solution, did you try

```
 git clone file:///local/path/to/repo-name.git
```

In your case:

```
 git clone file:///\\mymachine/shared/repo.git
```

It should work just fine.

---

Update August 2014 (4 years later), Git 2.1

[Commit c2369bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2369bdf7ff082d588c4a4efe280bc4a483d0192) by Eric Sunshine and [Cezary Zawadka (`czawadka`)](https://github.com/czawadka) means a simpler UNC path now work:

#### Windows: allow using UNC path for git repository

> Eric Sunshine fixed `mingw_offset_1st_component()` to return consistently "`foo`" for UNC "`//machine/share/foo`", cf [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/browse_thread/thread/c0af578549b5dda0).

So this should now work:

```
git clone //mymachine/shared/repo.git
```

Answer (score 11):

We use TortoiseGit. The URL's it accepts are //machinename/shared/repo.

Comment: Plain Git should accept URLs such as these without issue as well. Failing that, another possible approach might be to have every team member map the shared folder to a chosen drive letter (e.g. X:) and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

My post has a step by step guide to creating a distributed git repository using a windows share. I've found that a windows share works fine for small projects.

http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2011/08/30/getting-started-with-git-on-windows/#Creating_a_distributed_repository

Answer (score 0):

"I have a few **different computers** that I use at home and I wanted to set up GIT that I can access my code from any of them. It took me a bit because I was too used to working with a client-server model where I designate one machine as the "server" that holds the repository and everything else was a client. Instead, GIT seems to operate more like a merge tool and every local copy is its own "master." Once I understood that, it turns out that setting up GIT is very simple and just needs GIT itself and SSH".

To read more you can check this link: http://blog.lazyhacker.com/2010/04/setting-up-git-for-home-network.html