# Sharing your Source Code(PHP) on LAN

Tags: php, networking, file-sharing, code-sharing

We are two person, working on a same project. Our Source code is in PHP. We use `XAMPP` to test our code on `localhost`.

We are connected through LAN, We can see and change settings of Database by access to `http://192.168.192.XXX/phpmyadmin/` .

If person1 makes any changes in the code than he has to send it to the person 2 by email so that he may get the changed source code.

I want to know is there a method by which we can share our files on LAN. Because the Person 2 has to wait for person 1 to make changes and send the zip file.

is there a way by which we can keep only copy of the code , and both can access and make changes in it..

***FTP is blocked in our LAN.***

Comment: Best suggestion would be making use of `TFS` Plugin on `Eclipse Helios`.

Comment: You are looking for Version control! :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Comment: What you want is using a version control system such as GIT

Comment: Use any svn with http being used for file transfer instead of ftp.

Comment: Git repositories. Separate dev environments configured using Vagrant. Jenkins build server to publish changes to the integration and staging servers (on demand (with its UI) / on commit (with git hooks)).

Comment: ... the most popular choices are [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and Subversion. If you're on Windows and want to start easy, Subversion has a beautiful client: http://tortoisesvn.net/ and a very easy to install server: http://www.visualsvn.com/server/ But something like Git (being a distributed version control system) really is the future and worth learning.

Comment: "is there a method by which we can share our files on LAN." GIT doesn't really answer that...

Comment: Firstly GIT use FTP, and I think GIT is not the solution because, I have to use internet for that, I want to share on LAN, so that we work offline.

Comment: Git doesn't use FTP. It typically uses SSH. It doesn't require the use of the Internet unless you want to host a repository on the Internet (and even then, you only need the connection when you want to push and pull).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP may be blocked, but have you considered creating a network share? Of course, anyone on the lan that you setup the share with would have access to it as well.

If they know the location of the share, anyone can access it.

Comment: How Network Share, can you guide or give me a link... I had tried many windows sharing but none worked properly.

Comment: http://www.techradar.com/us/news/networking/windows-file-and-network-sharing-the-complete-guide-1119901

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for SVN and/or git

1. SVN http://subversion.apache.org/
2. GIT http://git.apache.org/

Comment: Firstly GIT use FTP, and I think GIT is not the solution because, I have to use internet for that, I want to share on LAN, so that we work offline. That is what is I am asking how can i share on LAN, I am using Windows 7 and Windows 8 :)

Comment: nor git neither svn needs any internet all you need to have a network (and you are already setup into a lan) and server setup with git, or with svn.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2230500/829533

Comment: all you need is a little research..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) for this, simple and it will solve your troubles :)

Or if not GIT, why you just dont share your folder with source code in your LAN? And then it will be accessible for both of you.

Comment: Firstly GIT use FTP, and I think GIT is not the solution because, I have to use internet for that, I want to share on LAN, so that we work offline. 
That is what is I am asking how can i share on LAN, I am using Windows 7 and Windows 8 :)

Comment: No, GIT doesnt need FTP... Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200181/how-to-git-clone-a-repo-in-windows-from-other-pc-within-the-lan, and also, you can share your folder in your network... so then you wont need GIT...